# Store a value from text field in a .txt

Tags: c++, winapi

My problem is very simple (at least i think it is). I'd like to capture a value from a text input and store it inside a txt file. Right now i'm using this code, and the action button is intended to write the content in file when clicked. But i'm getting the value of button registered in the file instead.

```
    case WM_CREATE:{
        CreateWindow(
            TEXT("EDIT"), TEXT("value"), 
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER, 
            190, 50, 50, 20,
            hwnd, (HMENU) NULL, NULL, NULL 
        );

        CreateWindow(
            TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Ok"), 
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 
            250, 10, 30, 20,
            hwnd, (HMENU) ID_BTN, NULL, NULL 
        );

        break;
    }

    case WM_COMMAND: {
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_BTN) {
            std::ofstream outfile;
            outfile.open("C:\\file.txt", std::ios_base::app);
            outfile << ID_BTN;
            outfile.close();
            MessageBox(hwnd, "Done!", "Title", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
              return 0;
         }
         break;
    }
```

Thanks.

---

**EDIT**: @ZanLynx, I tried to do what you have said, but compiler keep saying hwndText wasn't declared, when it was.

```
107 `hwndText' undeclared (first use this function)
```

Here's the code

```
#define ID_BTN 1
#define ID_TXT 2

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {

            HWND hwndText = CreateWindow(
                TEXT("Edit"), TEXT("Write here"), 
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,  
                190, 10, 100, 20, 
                hwnd, (HMENU) ID_TXT, NULL, NULL
            );

            CreateWindow(
                TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("OK"), 
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 
                250, 10, 30, 20,
                hwnd, (HMENU) ID_BTN, NULL, NULL
            );

            break;
        }

        case WM_COMMAND: 
        {

            if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_BTN) 
            {
                LRESULT iTextSize = SendMessage(hwndText, EM_GETLIMITTEXT, 0, 0);
                char *szText = new char[iTextSize];
                SendMessage(hwndText, WM_GETTEXT, iTextSize, (LPARAM)szText);

                std::ofstream outfile;
                outfile.open("C:\\f.txt", std::ios_base::app);
                outfile << szText;
                outfile.close();

                MessageBox(hwnd, "Done!", "Title", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                return 0;
            };  

            break;
        }

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are writing ID_BTN into outfile. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: You can send your edit box a `WM_GETTEXT` message.

Comment: Your hwndText is declared only inside the case block. You need to make it global, or make it part of some sort of Application structure, which could be global or heap allocated. In any case, it needs to persist between messages and be accessible by all the concerned functions.

Comment: @ZanLynx Ok ok, I got it. Much obliged, really, thanks to you I managed to make it work. :)

Answer (score 1):

Store the handle to your EDIT window.

Then you can use the [Edit Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions to get the text so you can write it into a file.

Comment: How can i store the value of EDIT in a handle? Sorry for the dumb question, but I've started to work with C++ yesterday.

Comment: @AllanDavidson: The result of the CreateWindow function is a window handle. Or an error. You really should check for errors in code that you write. It saves you from rude surprises and wondering why things do not work.

Comment: I edited the problem description. I'm still wonder why things do not work, cause I don't understand C++ structure very well, and unfortunately, I don't have time to go through a full learning since I'm running against the time. Thanks for you help mate.